# UIPageViewController vs UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

Simple question, I've done a decent amount of exploration around custom navigation / transitions between `UIViewController`s and am unclear about the following:

I'm looking for behavior similar to what `UIPageViewController` provides (non stack-based navigation forward and backwards through "pages" of content). But I want to be able to customize the transitions, and I want the transitions to be interactive linked to a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

It seems like the `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` protocol provides some of what I want (interactivity, custom transitions). But because transitions are invoked solely with `presentViewController:animated:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` it seems like it's built exclusively for use with stack-based navigation (ie `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`, modal presentation). Ie it doesn't seem like it'll play nice with something like `UIPageViewController`.

If I use `UIViewController` containment to build a custom container similar to `UIPageViewController` (see in progress demo [here](https://github.com/alfiehanssen/ios-viewcontroller-containment)) can I integrate the `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` protocol into this to drive the transitions? Or do I need to roll those on my own (currently I have a rough manual implementation of interactive transitions)?

Comment: Not an answer to the question exactly, but I had done a similar project and you can refer the source code. It uses Swipe gesture instead of pan gesture, but you can easily modify the source to make it pan. See it in the below link; https://github.com/surajthomask/SlidePanelsView

Answer (score 4):

I do a lot of custom animations in my apps that most developers shy away from because I use a lot of UIViewControlloer Containment in my work.

It's the simplest way to get the transitions that you're looking for.

Here's how I would go about it:

1. Create a base view controller; lets call it MainViewController. It will have references to all of the other view controllers and hold the logic for the transitions. It should also follow a protocol we'll define as ViewXControllerDelegate.
2. Create your other view controllers; lets call them View1Controller, View2Controller, View3Controller. Add an instance of each of them as private properties of MainViewController. In the init method of MainViewController, instantiate them and add their views as subviews of MainViewController's view. Should look something like this:

   ```
   self.v1c = [[View1Controller alloc]init];
   [self addChildViewController:self.v1c];
   [self.v1c didMoveToParentViewController:self];

   //Setup each subview so that its frame makes it off screen or
   //On screen depending on the app state and where you want each
   //subview to animate to/from

   [self.view addSubview:self.v1c.view];

   ....
   ```
3. Setup up a UIPanGestureRecognizer in each of your ViewXControllers that has its target and selector set to the parent view controller (MainViewController).
4. Handle all logic in your MainViewController class where you take the distance swiped, application state, the locations of each of the views into account (using helper properties in the ViewXControllers like "inactiveFrame" or "activeFrame" where the animation between them happens based on the percentage of movement that's occurred in the pan gesture.

Comment: If I have an instance (or subclass of) `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`  and a fully implemented animator (class complied to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol) how *exactly* do I put the two class together in my custom container view controller. Assume the container controller properly implements all view containment logic. I think that's the OP's original question as well (i.e. "how" to integrate.) Your answer just describe the setup I'm having but hand-wringed all the integration part.